# Flutter - 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I've been looking for a WordPress + Flutter App integration and found a good one, but I got this error message:

I'm pretty this is a simple error, but I'm more into a design guy than a dev, so would be great if some of you give me some tip about it. Thanks in advance!

```
import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    import '../config.dart';
    import '../model/post_entity.dart';

    class WpApi {
    static const String BASE_URL = URL + REST_URL_PREFIX + '/wp/v2/';

    static Future<List<PostEntity>> getPostsList(
      {int category = 0, int page = 1}) async {
    var posts = [];
    try {
      String extra = category != 0 ? '&categories=' + '$category' : '';

      dynamic response = await http.get(Uri.parse(BASE_URL +
          '''
      posts?_embed&page=$page''' +
          extra));
      dynamic json = jsonDecode(response.body);

      (json as List).forEach((v) {
        posts.add(PostEntity.fromJson(v));
      });
     } catch (e) {
      //TODO Handle No Internet Response
    }
    return posts;
    }

     static Future<List<PostCategory>> getCategoriesList({int page = 1}) async {
    List<PostCategory> categories = [];
    try {
      dynamic response = await http.get(Uri.parse(BASE_URL +
          'categories?orderby=count&order=desc&per_page=15&page=$page'));
      dynamic json = jsonDecode(response.body);

      (json as List).forEach((v) {
        categories.add(PostCategory.fromJson(v));
      });
     } catch (e) {
      //TODO Handle No Internet Response
     }
     return categories;
     }
     }
```

The error is on the return **posts**;

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<PostEntity>>')
```

Answer (score 0):

change `var posts = []` to `List<PostEntity> posts = []`

```
  static Future<List<PostEntity>> getPostsList(
      {int category = 0, int page = 1}) async {
    List<PostEntity> posts = []; //<-- change var posts = [] to List<PostEntity> posts = []
    try { ...
```

Comment: Hey, @Mehdi, thanksss! 

Now I'm getting the List of Categories, but still not getting the posts. Could you find any problem on my code?